# Mathematical notation of a cell based product between a vector and a matrix

Tags: matrices, notation

What is the mathematical notation of an operation that multiplies a vector, $v$, with a matrix, $X$, as in the following example:

$$ v = \begin{bmatrix}
v_{1} \\ 
v_{2} \\ 
v_{3} \\ 
v_{4} \\ 
v_{5} \end{bmatrix} 
, \qquad \mathbf{X} = \begin{bmatrix}
x_{11} & x_{12} & x_{13} \\
x_{21} & x_{22} & x_{23} \\
x_{31} & x_{32} & x_{33} \\
x_{41} & x_{42} & x_{43} \\
x_{51} & x_{52} & x_{53} \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

$$v\,??\,\mathbf{X} = \begin{bmatrix}
v_1 x_{11} & v_1 x_{12} & v_1 x_{13} \\
v_2 x_{21} & v_2 x_{22} & v_2 x_{23} \\
v_3 x_{31} & v_3 x_{22} & v_3 x_{33} \\
v_4 x_{41} & v_4 x_{32} & v_4 x_{43} \\
v_5 x_{51} & v_5 x_{52} & v_5 x_{53} \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

This is a common operation to prepare data analysis, e.g. with panel data where $v$ represents a treatment vector and $\mathbf{X}$ indicators for each year $t$:
\begin{array}{rr|rrrr|rrr} 
  id &   t &   v & x_1 & x_2 & x_3 & vx_1 & vx_2 & vx_3  \\ \hline
   1 &   1 &   1 &   1 &   0 &  0  &   1 &   0 &  0  \\
   1 &   2 &   1 &   0 &   1 &  0  &   0 &   1 &  0  \\
   1 &   3 &   0 &   0 &   0 &  1  &   0 &   0 &  0  \\ \hline
   2 &   1 &   1 &   1 &   0 &  0  &   1 &   0 &  0  \\
   2 &   2 &   0 &   0 &   1 &  0  &   0 &   0 &  0  \\
   2 &   3 &   1 &   0 &   0 &  1  &   0 &   0 &  1  \\ \hline
\end{array}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get your required output $Y$ as:

1. Diagonalize $v$ and multiply with $X$.

   The notation for this would be $\eqalign{M &= \operatorname{Diag}(v)\\Y &= MX}$
2. Make $v$ into a matrix with columns repeated, and then use the Hadamard product.

   The notation for this would be $\eqalign{M &= v \tt{1}^\top\\Y &= M\odot X}$

Comment: Both options are very elegant solutions. Many thanks!
Only, on the second option, I do not understand the notation for the Matrix $M$.

Comment: $\tt1^\top$ refers to a vector of the form $\begin{bmatrix}1 &1 &1\end{bmatrix}$. Multiplying $v=\begin{bmatrix} v_1 \\ v_2 \\ v_3 \end{bmatrix}$ with this, one gets $M = v\tt1^\top = \begin{bmatrix}v_1 &v_1 &v_1 \\ 
v_2 &v_2 &v_2 \\ 
v_3 &v_3 &v_3 \\ 
\end{bmatrix}$. Does this clarify what you were asking?

Comment: Yes, perfect clarification.

Answer (score 1):

If you separate the columns of $\mathbf{X}$ in your example into say $X_1$, $X_2$, and $X_3$, then each column of the output say $Y_1$, $Y_2$, $Y_3$, can be written as
$$Y_i = \text{diag}(v \, \otimes \, X_i),$$
where $\otimes$ is the [outer product of vectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_product) and diag forms a vector from the diagonal elements of a matrix.